# Как определить браузер в user agent через GET запрос приложения

Tags: java, android

Я развернул локальный сервер с кодом для определения user agenta. Из android studio через HttpURLConnection я делаю запрос на этот сервак и получаю ответ:

```
Dalvik/2.1.0 (Linux; U; Android 10; Android SDK built for x86 Build/QSR1.000000.000)
```

Если я открываю ссылку в webView, то я получаю полный ответ с указанием браузера.
Как мне получить полный ответ, вроде такого, без использования webView в моем запросе?

`Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; U; Android 4.0.3; ru-ru; LG-L160L Build/IML74K) AppleWebkit/534.30 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/4.0 Mobile Safari/534.3`0

Код на локальном сервере:

```
<?php 
echo $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'];
```

Код запроса:

```
private void getResponse() {
        TestSendRequestTask task = new TestSendRequestTask();
        try {
            String response = task.execute(url).get();
            Log.i("MyResponse", response);
        } catch (ExecutionException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    private class TestSendRequestTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {
        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... strings) {
            HttpURLConnection urlConnection = null;
            StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
            try {
                urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) new URL(strings[0]).openConnection();
                urlConnection.connect();
                urlConnection.setRequestMethod("GET");;
                if (HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK == urlConnection.getResponseCode()) {
                    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(urlConnection.getInputStream()));
                    String line;
                    while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                        builder.append(line);
                    }
                    return builder.toString();
                } else {
                    Log.i("MyError", "Ошибка");
                }
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } finally {
            }
            return null;
        }
    }
```

Я только набираюсь опыта и эта задачка мне сводит мозг уже несколько дней. Прошу помощи! Алярма!!!

Comment: `urlConnection.setRequestProperty("User-Agent","your user agent");`?

Comment: <s>Для начала надо научиться отличать "получаю" и "отправляю".</s> UPDATE: А, всё, я расшифровал вопрос...

Comment: @ЮрийСПб, а тебе - в ответы.

Comment: @Qwertiy, я просто был не уверен, что это правильно) Ни разу не приходилось использовать `HttpURLConnection`)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вам надо вручную добавить заголовок вот так:

```
urlConnection.setRequestProperty("User-Agent","your user agent");
```

Comment: Все работает) спасибо. Есть правда еще вопрос: А можно ли узнать реальный user agent?

Comment: @RatitMatarit, user-agent - это просто строчка в заголовке, который тоже является просто строчкой. Там может быть всё что угодно. Никакого "реального" user-agent просто не существует.

Comment: Что ж, я узнал больше, спасибо)

Answer (score 1):

В общем и целом решение вот такое и полностью рабочее:
При GET запросе через HttpURLConnection на сервер вам будет показан стоковый UA через Android Browser. Вариант рабочий заменить на `urlConnection.setRequestProperty("User-Agent","your user agent");`*Как написал коллега сверху*
Но если нужен реальный, то я получил так:
В нужной активности, в layout, создаем WebView и делаем его invisible;
В коде получаем его и слизываем UA через: `webView.getSettings().getUserAgentString();`
Сохраняем в переменную. Делаем ее публичной и статической.
И в классе унаследованного от AsyncTask мы эту переменную получаем и подставляем перед соединением.
Выглядит так:

```
Ваша Activity (пример: MyClass):
public static String user_agent;

WebView webView = findViewById(R.id.web);
user_agent = webView .getSettings().getUserAgentString();
```

И получаем в YourClass extends AsyncTask<>

```
String ua = MyClass.user_agent ;
connection.setRequestProperty("User-Agent", ua);
connection.connect();
```

Пар-пар-па = Все!

Comment: Можно и без скрытой `WebView` получить её user-agent:  [`WebSettings.getDefaultUserAgent(context)`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebSettings#getDefaultUserAgent(android.content.Context)), если нужна поддержка устройств с API<17, то можно применить такой трюк с рефлексией:  https://stackoverflow.com/a/23990155

Comment: Черт подери, где же вы были раньше!!!! Это просто суперское решение моих вопросов!!!